# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS detects there is an MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. what do I do about it?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, intel, bug

On examining my system log I found the following entry:

*Oct 23 10:38:00  kernel: [0.xxxx] MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.*

I checked the url given in the error report and I can see that it's a bug with Intel processors, but worrying and curious as to why I have only found out about this major vulnerability now when I migrated my pc away from Windows some years back.

The obvious question is, while its great that Ubuntu detects this major vulnerability where Windows does not, aside from detecting it, does the Ubuntu kernel actually do anything to mitigate it, I just want to know if my Ubuntu system is still open to this vulnerability or if its secure?

Comment: Have you searched for "intel MDS bug"? It was pretty well covered in the tech press in May 2019 when it was disclosed along with details of Ubuntu and Window updates and finally Intel CPU microcode to mitigate the issues

Comment: Also as with all security questions, what is "secure" entirely depends on what your personal treat model is.